# Does a shot hitting the woodwork count as a "shot on target" in football?

Tags: football, statistics

Is a shot that hits the woodwork considered a shot on target? Apparently this is not counted in the EPL and La Liga? Is this true? I searched all of this extensively but could not find anything.

Comment: I can't support it with a reference (hence why it is not an answer), but on target generally means that it would have gone in if not for a save (either by the goalkeeper or another defender). This information may help someone find an appropriate reference.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on who is taking the records.

The argument for **ex**cluding it is that being on target means it should go in unless it is blocked. It wasn't blocked and didn't go in, therefore it's not on target.

The argument for **in**cluding it is that being on target means it would hit the face of the goal, which includes the face of the posts and crossbar, so hitting these is still hitting the target and therefore it was on target.

Answer (score 1):

No, a shot on target is anything inside the woodwork.

If a shot was inside the woodwork but deflected onto the woodwork then this would count as a shot on target.